# Having trouble measuring runtime of algorithm by counting steps

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm having some trouble counting the steps for this algorithm consisting of the following nested loops:

```
for(int i=1; i <= N; i++) 
       for(int j=1; j <= i; j++) 
             for(int k=1; k <= i*log(j); k++) 
                  x=i+j+k;
```

I need to calculate the runtimes for n = 10, 20, 40, 100, 200, 400, 1000, 2000, 4000, 10000, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please specifically note what issues you have with calculating it. If it's a problem in theoretical informatics, please don't ask on StackOverflow, this site is programming only!

Comment: are you looking for some mathematical formula as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This counts the amount of "steps" in your loops:

```
int steps = 0;
for(int i=1; i <= N; i++) {
    for(int j=1; j <= i; j++) {
         for(int k=1; k <= i*log(j); k++) {
              steps++;
              x=i+j+k;
         }
    }
}
```

This one actually times it if that's what you want:

```
time_t start = time(0);
for(int i=1; i <= N; i++) 
    for(int j=1; j <= i; j++) 
        for(int k=1; k <= i*log(j); k++) 
            x=i+j+k;
time_t end = time(0);

time_t timeTaken = end - start;
```

If you need higher precision, look up a high precision clock

Comment: I think one `step++`  inside the innermost for loop is sufficient to count the total steps.

Comment: Both results (the one in the comment and the one in the answer) will asymptotically be of the order O(n log n).

Comment: @srini Oh lol! You are completely right. I made this answer late at night, so that probably explains it. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Just set the value for N to 20 (or other values you need) inside your program and don't use any I/O functions (cout/cin) and after the execution of the for loops, the program will end and cmd will report with the time it took to execute.